# If else condition in rotating of images in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation

i have a button in a collection view cell on which when user click it rotates the image. I have four angles for rotating the image, But i'm confused in a bit logic that how can i rotate an image in an image view on clicking to different angles. The image should rotate to only these four angles when complete the four angles if again it want to change angles user should be able to change the angle again from that four. 
Four angles are these,

```
 _imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);

_imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_4);

_imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);

_imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI*2);
```

Comment: and what is not working?

Comment: You question is not so clear. What do you mean by `But i'm confused in a bit logic that how can i rotate an image in an image view on clicking to different angles.`? I thought you are using a  `UIButton` to change the angles of the `UIImageView`

Comment: i want a logic on a click of a button when user click first the image should rotate to  M_PI angle and if again user click it should rotate to M_PI_4 and same with others. @Rhenz

Comment: i want logic how can i rotate it in these four angles when we click a button. @Lu_

Comment: I'm trying to understand your question. You want an action where when you pressed the button, the image will rotate at M_PI, then when you pressed the `UIButton` again it will rotate to M_MP_4 and so on? Is that right?

Comment: yes this is what i want. @Rhenz

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to do it like this.

1. Create an array that will hold the rotation values like

`let mpix2 = M_PI*2
let rotationValues = [M_PI, M_PI_4, M_PI_2, mpix2]`

2. Create a variable that will hold the current state of the image view, in this case, you can just use the index of the array

`var currentIndex = 0`

3. Create a function that will hold handle the logic when you pressed the button

`func rotateImage() {
    _imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotationValues[index])
    if currentIndex != rotationValues.count-1 {
        currentIndex = currentIndex + 1
    } else {
        // reset the current index back to zero
        currentIndex = 0 
    }
}`

Comment: Bro please in objective c . @Rhenz

Comment: can u do it i objective c. @Rhenz

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate your `UIImageView` right, the value must be greater than 0 and if you want to rotate to the left the value must be negative. For example -90.

First get current angle/transformation by

```
CGFloat angle = atan2f(yourView.transform.b, yourView.transform.a);
```

Then add your desired rotation angle to `angle` variable and pass it to that created function to rotate the `imageView`

```
CGFloat degrees = <Your desired angle>; //the value in degrees
CGFloat radians = degrees * M_PI/180;
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians);
```

You can create a function in which you can pass specific angle from your array of angles and `imageView` will be rotated,

Comment: but how can i rotate evertime when click on a button? @Paras Gorasiya

Comment: Just make a function from above code and call that function on every button click event.

Comment: thats what the logic i want i'm confused how to make this.@Paras Gorasiya

Comment: whats the value in b and a? @Paras Gorasiya

Comment: You should replace yourView with you imageView.

Comment: But according to ur code it is rotating image in just one angle i want it to rootate in four different angles. @Paras Gorasiya

Comment: Please check my updated answer, you need to replace the value of degrees with whatever angle you want to rotate to. Its as simple as that.